# Line chart X Axis interval range

Tags: c#, charts

I have a simple project where I need to display a line chart in Winforms. The data is coming from a CSV that I load into a Datatable. I have 2 columns that I need to take into account in the chart that I want to display.

First I have the column with the data for the Y axis. Let's call it the Y column. Then I have the Cycle column, which will be my X axis. For each cycle, I have about 60 Y value (this number vary). That's where my problem come from. Normally for each Y value I believe in a line chart you have just one X value.

As the data is in correct order the display is exactly how it's suppose to be. You can see here my current graph with the default intervals :

[image: Current chart with defaults intervals]

Here is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(); //Cycle column
   y[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][78]); //Y column
}
chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
```

However I am having trouble with the display of the intervals.

For each CSV, there is between 10 and 13 cycle. I need to display on the chart where each and every cycle finish. Approximatly, each "V" in the chart is a cycle.

I tried to put the xAxis interval to 1, but obviously it didn't work. Another thing I tried was to play with a percentage column I have. What the column tell me is at what percentage of the cycle the current line is. I added another column in my DataTable. Each time the percentage was 100%, I added the number of the cycle in that new column and if it's not an end of a cycle I leave it blank. Then I used that column as the X Axis but it didn't show any intervals at all.

I have no idea how to display the correct intervals. I tried to search online and found nothing but I am not quite sure what keywords to use for what I want to do. If somebody can point me in the right direction it would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: _x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();_ Why on earth would you convert the x-values to strings?? Always a mistake! correct and report back. if you want to set intervals to the low points you need to find the number of DataPoints between them; and __they need to be regular__! Otherwise you can't use the GridLines. Drawing vertical lines in one of the xxxPaint events would be the last resort..

Comment: Note: The basic unit of information in a Chart is the DataPoint. For lines (and splines and point types) each has one x- and one y-value. These can be set freely. All points are part of a Series and you can have multiple SEires overlapping and each with a frw choice of chartTypes. -

Comment: Thank you for the input. I corrected the .ToString() part. As my interval are not regular then I believe I won't be able to do exactly what I want to do.

Comment: You can analyze the data to find the values where you want vertical lines. Several ways to then create them, e.g. adding VerticalLineAnnotatons or code the PostPaint event to draw them..